# Why is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{x<n\leq\infty}a_{n}n^{-s}= 0$ a sufficient condition for convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Assume the following is true

$$\left|\sum_{x_{1}<n\leq x_{2}}\frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}\right| \leq Kx_{1}^{-\sigma}$$

where $s=\sigma+it$ and $a_n$ are complex, and all other variables are real, and $\sigma>0$.

We say that the magnitude of the sum on the LHS is *bounded*. Being bounded doesn't necessarily mean it *converges*.

If $x_1 \rightarrow \infty$ then the RHS tends to zero. The bound on the LHS tends to zero.

**Question:** Why does this mean the sum $\sum_{x_{1}<n\leq x_{2}}a_{n}n^{-s}$ *converges*?

**Notes:** If the the magnitude of individual terms went to zero, this would not be considered a sufficient (although it is necessary) for convergence. Why is it sufficient that the magnitude of the tail $\sum_{x<n\leq\infty}a_{n}n^{-s}$ of the series tends to zero?

---

This question is about convergence and bounds. The context is Apostol's proof that a Dirichlet Series has an abscissa of convergence. Apostol IANT section 11.6 pages 232-233. I think the question is independent of this context, but is referenced in case I am wrong.

Comment: Convergence of a series is the statement that it's partial sums converge. Your condition says that differences of partial sums go to zero, which implies convergence (this is completeness of the complex numbers)

Comment: This is just a special case of the definition of a sequence in $\mathbf C$ to be a Cauchy sequence. Being Cauchy implies convergence due to completeness in $\mathbf C$: for partial sums $s_n = c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n$, the partial sums are Cauchy when $|s_n - s_m| \to 0$ as $m, n \to \infty$.  For you, take $c_k = a_k/k^s$.  You should review what Cauchy sequences are and what the Cauchy criterion looks like for partial sums of an infinite series.

Comment: thanks for the comments vujazzman and @kcd - for me, I will be learning about Cauchy sequences for the first time! :)

Comment: @Tariq one way to think about it is that if the tail converges to zero then the part before the tail remains constant.